# how to make python read file from notepad and give the value

Tags: python, list, for-loop, input, notepad

hello guys so i have this notepad containing country and capital list.
then i want to make input of the country name to reveal the capital so this is where i get confused.

```
country.txt
malaysia, vietnam, myanmar, china, sri lanka, japan, brazil, usa, australia, thailand, russia, uk
kuala lumpur, hanoi, yangon, beijing, colombo, tokyo, rio, washington, canberra, bangkok, moscow, london
```

thats the notepad file for the country and capital

```
f = open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\country.txt')
count = 0
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    rec = line.split(',')
    count = count + 1

ctry = input('\nEnter country name: ')
ctry = ctry.lower()

for i in country:
    if ctry == country[i]:
        print ('country:', ctry)
        print ('capital:', capital[i])
        break
else:
    print ('country not in the list')
```

here is where i don't know what to do to make it work.

i want the output to be like

```
Enter country name: vietnam 
Country: vietnam 
Capital:  hanoi
```

and when there's no country on the list

```
Enter country name: france 
Country not in the list
```

Comment: What is in your `country` variable? What kind of error did you get?

Comment: same with `capital[i]`, `capital` is not defined here

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Q3.py", line 13, in <module>
    for i in country:
NameError: name 'country' is not defined```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here are some reasons why your code isn't working and some suggestions too:

- You didn't define the variables country or capital, so you were comparing the input with nothing, this will raise an error because the variable wasn't defined.
- If you open a file, you should close it after manipulate it, as suggestion it's better to use `with`.
- Please, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) about how for loops works, because you were trying to index `country[i]`, knowing that `i` is an element not an integer index.

Nonethless, you could try this:

```
with open(r'C:/Users/User/Desktop/country.txt') as f:
    lines=f.read().splitlines()
    countries=lines[0].strip().split(', ')
    cities=lines[1].strip().split(', ')
count = 0

print(countries)
print(cities)


ctry = input('\nEnter country name: ')
ctry = ctry.lower()

for i in countries:
    if i == ctry:
        print ('country:', ctry)
        print ('capital:', cities[countries.index(i)])
        break
else:
    print ('country not in the list')
```

Output:

```
countries
>>>['malaysia', 'vietnam', 'myanmar', 'china', 'sri lanka', 'japan', 'brazil', 'usa', 'australia', 'thailand', 'russia', 'uk']

cities
>>>['kuala lumpur', 'hanoi', 'yangon', 'beijing', 'colombo', 'tokyo', 'rio', 'washington', 'canberra', 'bangkok', 'moscow', 'london']

>>>'\nEnter country name: ' uk
>>>country: uk
>>>capital: london
```

Comment: thank you for this. i need more work and practise on the for loops.

Comment: You're welcome, and no worries, keep on practicing! :)